# Should you use a separate SSH session for each upload from a web app

Tags: java, session, ssh, jsch

In web-apps its often need to upload files via SSH(by SFTP protovol) to remote hosts with static content.
The question is: what is the best practice to work with SSH connection in such situation?
Do I need to create session(connect) every time, user upload a picture or a file?

Currently, I solved it with singleton bean with type com.jcraft.jsch.Session in the context. On web-app startup, is creates a session bean and do connect. So when cames request to upload file, the session is ready to do it. But in case of network problem, session will be destroyed and server need to reconnect. How to do it?

Comment: Is this a question about ssh via java or about how to do file uploads? if the latter - are you aware of the commons package? http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Comment: this question is about keeping ssh session open all the time and problems related with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If reconnect for every upload is too expensive for you, you should implement SSH connection pool. I'm not aware of such pools existent for SSH protocol. You may adapt ideas from HTTP connection pools - see [ThreadSafeClientConnManager](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/tags/4.1.3/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java) from apache HttpClient.